# How to print the matched string at the position of the data?

Tags: regex, perl

I tried to print the matched string at the postion of data,how can i do it?

```
$at ="at";
@ar = <DATA>;
@xxv = map(m/$at/g, @ar);
print "@ar";
print @xxv;
print "\n";
__DATA__
atgacaagcagacccaggggatacgat
```

I expected output is

```
    atgacaagcagacccaggggatacgat
    at                  at   at
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the desired output through `s///`

```
$at ="at";
$ar = <DATA>;
print $ar;
$ar =~ s/$at(*SKIP)(*F)|./ /g;
print $ar;
__DATA__
atgacaagcagacccaggggatacgat
```

**Output:**

```
atgacaagcagacccaggggatacgat
at                  at   at
```

`$at(*SKIP)(*F)` expands the variable `$at` and matches the same set of characters stored in the variable against the input string. Following `(*SKIP)(*F)` causes the match to fail and forces the pattern on the right side of `|` to match against the remaining characters. So `.` matches all the characters except the ones which are skipped. Replacing those matched characters with a space will give you the desired output.

**References:**

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
- [How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

Comment: Thank you for answering, But your answer is not fit for the perl cgi  `$ar = join("",@da);
print $ar,'<br>';
$ar =~ s/at(*SKIP)(*F)|./&nbsp/g;
print $ar;`  Not correctly fit with the data. How can i do it?

Comment: do you have the document on the special flag like SKIP and F, I'm unable to look for them on Google. It's the first time I see those flags

Comment: @Avinash raj Thank you for answering . Im using courier which is fit for me. and also use you code. Plese add document about `skip`

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $at ="at";
my $ar ="atgacaagcagacccaggggatacgat";

(my $x = $ar) =~ s/./ /g;

substr($x, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0]-1) = $at while $ar =~ /$at/g;

print "$ar\n$x\n";
```

As per your comments, it seems that you want to print the result into a webbroser. So, of course, you need a non proportional font. Either you go

```
 print "<pre>";
 print "$ar\n";
 print "$x";
 print "</pre>";
```

or you specify *monospace*:

```
 print "<div style='font-family:monospace'>");
 print "$ar<br>";
 print "$x";
 print "</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, But your answer is not fit for the perl cgi $ar = join("",@da); print $ar,'<br>'; $ar =~ s/at(*SKIP)(*F)|./&nbsp/g; print $ar; Not correctly fit with the data. How can i do it?

Comment: @Rene Nyffenegger  I'm remove   `-1` from your code, like `($x, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0])`  and run it, also works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` with a regex, instead of `map`.

```
$data = "atgacaagcagacccaggggatacgat" ;

my @chunks = split(/at/, $data) ;

print $data ; #echo input

#skip over non-matching chunks and print matches
foreach my $chunk (@chunks) {
    print ' ' x length($chunk) ;
    print 'at' ;
}
```

This will print an extra 'at' at the end, but I am too lazy to clean that up here.

Comment: Thank you for answering, But your answer is not fit for the perl cgi $ar = join("",@da); print $ar,'<br>'; $ar =~ s/at(*SKIP)(*F)|./&nbsp/g; print $ar; Not correctly fit with the data. How can i do it?

Comment: I don't understand why you bring in *cgi* now.

Answer (score 0):

@user3384402 Previous answers are enough for what you expect.

I think you try to sequence alignment. In the browser visualization that the space is not fit for target it is your problem.

Just do simple, use the `courier` or `courier new` font family it is give the correct visual effects. Bioinformatician when handle with the sequence alignment used these fonts only.  Try it.

Comment: thank you. Im used the courier font which is fit for me